# Admin middleware for method laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel i have a route:

```
$router->get('/create', 'NewsController@create');
```

And NewsController:

```
public function create()
{
    $this->middleware('user');


}
```

But `$this->middleware('user');` not working for me. how to restrict access only to this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You apply it in the constructor

```
class NewsController extends Controller {


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('user', ['only' => 'create']);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: What if I want multiple method use the same middleware?

Comment: This worked for me in first attempt - much to my surprise:
    $this->middleware('auth', ['only' => array('create', 'index')]);

Comment: you can also apply it to your routes like so: http://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2015-laravel-5-routes-restricting-based-on-user-type